# Passive FTP with Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ftp

I am trying to use Appengine (Java) to connect to a ftp server in passive mode.
As you may known, passive mode use 2 simultanous connections : 1 on port 21, and another on port chosen by the server. The problem I encounter, is that the two connections are not done from the same IP, as Appengine Socket Api use a load balencer and therefore issues connections with different source IPs. The problem with this is that the FTP server simply deny IPs that haven't initiated connection on port 21.
Is there any way to keep the same source IP for successive socket connection ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in app-engine.
If you own the FTP server, consider relaxing this condition.
If not, you can use a [compute engine vm with external IPs](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#ephemeraladdress) in the same project to get the file and then keep it in GCS or some shared storage.

Comment: Actually I already succeeded to make ftp work on Appengine, I open multiple sockets on the ephemeral port until the connection is accepted. But in my opinion this solution is not safe and is dependent on load balencer pool size. I will try to fork apache commons net project.

Comment: From GAE documentation : You cannot create a listen socket; you can only create outbound sockets.